# Flutter - How to align button to right side of the Row

Tags: flutter

I have an issue with aligning a add button to right side of the row.
I tried using SizedBox, MainAxisAlignment and increasing the width of buttons and containers, but it didn't work.It's moving to the left side instead and decreases the width of TextField.I guess it's because of Flexible class i used to create Row with TextField
[image]

```
Widget buildParty() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          border: Border.all(width: 0.7, color: Colors.black38),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: 30,
              height: 60,
              child: Text('$_prtnum'),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Participant')
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_prtadd > 1)
                  --_prtadd;
              });
            }, child: Text('-', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
                minimumSize: Size(34, 10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 5)
            ),),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: 35,
              child: Text('$_prtadd'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_prtadd < 8)
                  ++_prtadd;
              });
            }, child: Text('+', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(5), bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0))
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
                minimumSize: Size(34, 10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 5)
            ),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Remove padding from top widget and manage space accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this property in style of the right side button widget :
`tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`

```
 style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0))),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
            minimumSize: Size(34, 10),
            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 22,
              horizontal: 0,
            ),
          )
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the Align class in flutter to position the widgets.

```
Container(
     
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
),)
```

You can also align the button to the bottom and top right aswell but replacing centerRight with bottomRight or topRight.

Another way of doing it is but setting the alignment:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment(0.2, 0.6),
```

For more clarity go to :

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html

Comment: Perfect for me to align a button on the left side :                    child: Container(
                      height: 30.0,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed:

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `Flexible` with `Expanded`, as it'll acquire the rest of the space

Comment: It returns an issue "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."

Answer (score 0):

@Amil I have updated your code. Please use below code and you are good to go:-

```
 Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
      border: Border.all(width: 0.7, color: Colors.black38),
    ),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 30,
          height: 60,
          child: Text('$_prtnum'),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Participant')
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_prtadd > 1)
              --_prtadd;
          });
        }, child: Text('-', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
            minimumSize: Size(34, 10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 5)
        ),),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 35,
          child: Text('$_prtadd'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_prtadd < 8)
              ++_prtadd;
          });
        }, child: Text('+', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(5), bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0))
            ),
            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,

            alignment: Alignment.center,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
            minimumSize: Size(34, 10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 5)
        ),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and remove horizontal padding from 2nd `ElevatedButton`

functions:

```
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter--;
    });
  }
```

Widgtes:

```
   Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            border: Border.all(width: 0.7, color: Colors.black38),
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 15,
          ),
          padding:const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                '$_counter',
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              const Flexible(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Participant'),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
                    minimumSize: const Size(34, 10),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 22, horizontal: 5)),
                child: const Text(
                  '-',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 35,
                child: Text(
                  '$_counter',
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _decrementCounter,
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0))),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
                  minimumSize: const Size(34, 10),
                  tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 22,

                  ),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  '+',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Result-> [image]